# Laravel getting routes from database

Tags: laravel, eloquent, routes

I would like to ask, if is possible to get something like dynamic routes in Laravel. 
I have a personal CMS, based on modules. Each module == controller. In database, I have a table called "structure", where are stored all subsites of page. The **name** of item should be any, so I don't know the name of the item, because it is based on user's wishes. So article module should be named as "news", "articles", "blog" etc. I don't know. It means, I can't set the route to exact word, cause its name could be anything. This is, why I have stored this data to database. In database I have also module_name, which will point to controller.

So, if user will set for example:
*Blog -> module Article*,
I need to get route from db like this:

```
Route::get('/Blog/', 'ArticleController@index');
```

Both "Blog" and "Article" are stored in DB.

My problem is, I am unable to retrieve this data from DB. How should I do that, from the view of "best practices"? 
I tried to write

```
use DB;
```

in top of routes/web.php, but it doesn't work. And I also think, this is code ballast.

If anyone can help me with this, I would be thankfull. Thank you

Comment: I think you need to read up on laravel's ORM and Route Model Binding.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding  Or ... just subcontract it to me.  I do this type of thinng all the time.

Answer (score 1):

actually don't know why you want do that

are you meaning something like this

```
// route
Route::get('/{slug}', 'RedirectController@redirect');

// RedirectController
public function redirect($slug)
{
    // in your example slug is the column name of the 'Blog'
    $to = \DB::table('route_table')->where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

    // module is the column name of Article
    return redirect()->action($to->module . 'Controller@index');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Route like this, set up a wildcard

```
Route::get('/{name}', 'ArticleController@show');
```

Then in your controller, for index() method:

```
public function show($name)
{
//$name now is equal to whatever the user put into the route
//do some database stuff with $name to fetch the proper data
}
```

Comment: @index should be a listing.  change it to @show($name)

Comment: @TarekAdam Yes that would be best practices

Comment: I'm afraid it won't work. I have more modules that only articles. I need also to set routes for gallery, contact-form, static page, etc etc. What do you think?

Comment: @MegoSoft check out Route Model Binding.  You're better off with the ORM than the DB:: statements.

Comment: As I'm writting. I don't know the exact names of subsites. Each module should be available on any url.

Comment: What's a module?

Comment: @MegoSoft So then set up wildcard routes like such
Route::get('/gallery/{name}', 'Controller@method');
Route::get('/contact-form/{name}', 'Controller@method');
etc, etc. And set up proper methods to output proper views based on the type of route?

Comment: @MegoSoft you should separate your "modules" into Route::group() 's

Comment: @Polaris No way. I need to get rid of name of module in url :( The project is not in English, it is in Slovak. And what if there will be a multilingual site? Every necessary information about routes is in my database. Why is dynamically routes so hard thing in laravel? I have thought it is one of the base thinks, the coder should need :-/

Comment: So then stick with a top-level wildcard route. /{name}
And then in your method, look up the name in your database to determine the information about the module?

Comment: @Polaris ehm. That probably should be a way. But I'm not happy with this solution, cause my next problem will be to create new function and explore in each  controller what should do. Are you absolutely sure, that there's no way how to use class DB in routes/web.php?

Comment: @MegoSoft You wouldn't want to use DB facade in web.php anyway, you are mixing up MVC and it's bad practice.

Ideally you would have one controller for all wildcard routes, and depending on what that wildcard results to, determine how your controller method will handle it. Can you give me an example of what you are trying to do exactly? I'm still a little unclear.